# Groovy script is failing for input variable of List type from User Defined Variable

Tags: jmeter

In my response I have two values, `name` and `uuid` and I want to fetch the `name` and its `uuid` which is equal the list I am providing from user defined variable. This works fine when I am giving single value in my user defined variable but when I am trying to give a list of name it is returning empty value.

Sample Response Data:

```
{
    "page": {
        "number": 1,
        "more": 0,
        "rows": 5000
    },
    "accounts": [
        {
            "name": "NewStudy_271022",
            "uuid": "e13d25f7-fd62-4e7b-a3f5-1183c4595d62"
        },
        {
            "name": "ParseInfo2",
            "uuid": "07ebedf3-1088-4293-a850-6b3ac39b7018"
        },
        {
            "name": "Anony_01_JAN",
            "uuid": "802add0c-722b-4a15-9c13-a0a8b838f3a1"
        },
        {
            "name": "TESTDE28644",
            "uuid": "2fb6f511-84f3-4576-a383-b9d41828165a"
        },
        {
            "name": "D_Anonymization",
            "uuid": "bcb8c332-506c-43be-9d24-438bf0057e2c"
        },
        {
            "name": "sm1888",
            "uuid": "907f5546-caa9-4585-8e9b-d046485c1aec"
        },
        {
            "name": "Test_Study_567",
            "uuid": "41884e7e-70fa-4690-81a0-e30c2479400c"
        }
    ],
    "status": "OK"
}
```

Using a JSON Extractor for getting all the names.

[image]

Code Block:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;

def completeFetchedStudyNameFromResponse = []; 
1.upto(vars.get('allStudyNameFetched_matchNr') as int, {
  index ->
  completeFetchedStudyNameFromResponse.add(vars.get('allStudyNameFetched_' + index));
});

String tempToBeExcludedStudyName = vars.get('excludeStudyName');

def toBeDeleteStudy = [];
def studyNameNeedToExcludeFromDeletion = new JsonSlurper().parseText(tempToBeExcludedStudyName);

def filteredStudyName = completeFetchedStudyNameFromResponse.findAll {
  studyName ->
    studyNameNeedToExcludeFromDeletion.every {
      keywords ->
       //!studyName.contains(keywords);
         studyName.contains(keywords);
    }
}
def bdConverter = new JsonSlurper();
def responseBDTemp = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
def responseBD = bdConverter.parseText(responseBDTemp);
def resultStudyUUIDCollector = [];
def parsedResultBD = responseBD.accounts;


filteredStudyName.each { studyNameFew ->
  resultStudyUUIDCollector.add(responseBD.accounts.find { account -> account.name == studyNameFew }.uuid)  
}

vars.putObject("myList", resultStudyUUIDCollector);
```

In the code am trying to check if the name contains the provide name from user defined variable or not,

`!studyName.contains(keywords);` this works fine as well for input variable like `["D_Anonymization","ParseInfo2"]` from the user defined variable(I am able to retrieve the name which doesn't contain the given list)

Using `studyName.contains(keywords);` logic I am trying to retrieve the name and uuid which is matching the list. The above logic work for single entry in the list but when I am giving more than more than 1 I am getting 0 (empty) in return.

Error for more than 1 entries in the list:

User Defined variable:

[image]

Error message:

[image]

Works fine for Single Value:

[image]

[image]

Success Message:

for single entries

[image]

for single entries

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to get the following construction in `myList`:

```
[e13d25f7-fd62-4e7b-a3f5-1183c4595d62, 802add0c-722b-4a15-9c13-a0a8b838f3a1, 2fb6f511-84f3-4576-a383-b9d41828165a, 907f5546-caa9-4585-8e9b-d046485c1aec, 41884e7e-70fa-4690-81a0-e30c2479400c]
```

you could do something like:

```
def accounts = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).accounts
def toExclude = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(vars.get('excludeStudyName'))
vars.putObject('myList', accounts.findAll { account -> !toExclude.contains(account.name) }.collect { account -> account.uuid })
```

If you want JSON representation like this:

```
[
  "e13d25f7-fd62-4e7b-a3f5-1183c4595d62",
  "802add0c-722b-4a15-9c13-a0a8b838f3a1",
  "2fb6f511-84f3-4576-a383-b9d41828165a",
  "907f5546-caa9-4585-8e9b-d046485c1aec",
  "41884e7e-70fa-4690-81a0-e30c2479400c"
]
```

add another line:

```
vars.put('myListJSON', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(vars.getObject('myList')).toPrettyString())
```

JSON Extractor is not required.

More information:

- [Apache Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)